# Unknown referenced nature: org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature

Tags: spring-tool-suite

In STS 4, my Java 10 Spring Boot 2.1 project warns me:

> Unknown referenced nature:
>   org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a left-over from a prior STS brought-in by the `.project` file due to a [known issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/issues/49).

To fix this, delete the project from your workspace(s) in STS, and remove the project meta-data from the file system:

```
  rm .project
  rm .classpath
  rm .factorypath
  rm -rf .settings
```

When you re-import the project, STS 4 will build proper project meta-data.

Comment: In case this wasn't obvious to whoever reads this answer. This should work, but, it wipes all project metadata. So it is best to **remove the projects from your workspace first** and re-import them aftwards. Doing this with the projects in the workspace may confuse Eclipse and Eclipse will then recreate some empty / vanilla .project files, leaving you basically again with a 'bogus' .project file to deal with.

Comment: I've updated the answer to make that point more clear -- thanks, @Kris.

Comment: Answer is not clear. What do you mean by delete the project in STS?

Comment: "Delete the project" -> right click on project, select delete.

Answer (score 14):

Open the .project file in your source folder and comment/delete this line:

```
<nature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</nature>
```

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer. It is cleaner, faster and easier to implement than what is marked as the correct answer.

Answer (score 4):

I saw this problem after installing Eclipse Jee-2019-03 and using it for a workspace created by Eclipse Oxygen.

My answer is similar to Amadán, but I did not see Spring in the right-click dropdown of the project... because I has not installed the Spring tools yet.

I did this:
Right-click on the project --> Properties --> Project Natures
click on springnature --> Remove
click Help --> Eclipse Marketplace...
Find:  Spring  --> click Go
on the Spring Tools 4 - for Spring Boot --> click Install

after that my project worked and I did not have to add springnature to the Project Natures

Answer (score 1):

You might also try to just:

1. remove the Spring nature

   - right click on the project > Spring > Remove Spring Project Nature
2. add the Spring nature again

   - right click on the project > Spring > Add Spring Project Nature